# What should I say when I see bad deed?

Tags: deeds

There are some specific words for certain deeds like when someone give us gift we say "jazakAllah". Then what should I say when I see bad deed.

Comment: In case you see bad deed you should even consider changing it or advising the person doing it too. In Islam witnessing something wrong and keeping silent is a sin unless one is not able to act!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever we see bad deeds first of all we shuold try to stop them.

> On the authority of Abu saeed al-khudree(ra) who said:
>   "I heard the messanger of ALLAH (saw),"whosoever of you sees an evil,let him his hand;and if he is not able to do so then[let him change it] with his tounge; and if he is not able to do so'then with heart -and that is the weakest of faith"
>      [MUSLIM]

or we shold say "NAUZBILLAH" WHEN see the bad deeds.
and shold also pray that:

> "allahahuma innee auudu bika min munkaraatil-alkhlaq, wal-amaal wal-ahwaa.(sunan ATTERMIDHIY#3591.
>
> "O ALLAH!I seek refuge in you from reprehesible deeds and whims"